# How to read data in Python 2.7-Panda with no header information

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I am using Panda and iPython and I want to load the data but it has no header info.
I would like to have inserted header info such as 'number', 'title', 'category'.

My .dat file looks like this:

> 1::movie_title1 (1995)::comedy|thriller|romance
>   2::movie_title2 (2000)::adventure|romance
>   3::movie_title3 (1977)::comedy|action|children

As of right now, I have:

> from pandas import Series, DataFrame
>   import pandas as pd
>   frame = pd.read_table('/home/me/movies.dat', delimiter='::', usecols=(1,2,3))

Which outputs a table like:

> null, Toy Story (1995), Animation|Children's|Comedy
>   0, Jumanji (1995), Adventure|Children's|Fantasy
>   1,  Grumpier Old Men (1995), Comedy|Romance

PS This is not homework, I just want to figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

Pass `header=None` to `read_table`.  See [the documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.io.parsers.read_table.html).